# Multiple portlets project

Tags: java, portlet

Have a question, If i have a severel portlets how to call one of they?
For example if i have one portlet that i write his name in `portlet.xml`

```
 <portlet-class>ru.my-portlet</portlet-class>
```

And when i want to call it i write like this

```
<form name="form" action="<portlet:actionURL/>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div id="up">
     <input id="fileUpload1" type="file" name="filename1"value="Browse..."/>
   </div>
   <div>
    <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Загрузить">
    <input type="button" id="del" onclick="deleting()" value="Удалить">
   </div>
</form>
```

What i gonna do if i have several portlets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, there is no way to get a (action, render, ...) URL of another portlet. Portlet specs do not cover this.

In JSR-286 compliant portal containers, one might use portlet events to change state of another portlet, or public render parameters (given the assumption portlets share the same portal page) to influence render behvaior of another portlet. Both is discussed [here](http://developers.sun.com/portalserver/reference/techart/jsr286/jsr286.html).

Portal containers might also provide a container-specific extension of inter portlet communication - it might be worth checking docs of your container as well.